# Changing element ID with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am loading in the following navbar html from a required PHP file:

```
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="applying.php">Applying</a></li>
        <li><a href="current.php">Current <br />Residents</a></li>
        <li><a href="alumni.php">Alumni</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Depending on the page that I am on (let's say I am on the alumni.php page) I want that list item to be given the ID "active"?

Edit:  Here is my header.php code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/navbar.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">
            <img src="images/tree.png" alt="tree" width="87" height="98"></img>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <
        </div>
    </div>  
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="index.php" id="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="applying.php">Applying</a></li>
            <li><a href="current.php">Current <br />Residents</a></li>
            <li><a href="alumni.php">Alumni</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I assume that I need to do this through Javascript once the page loads?  How would I do this?

Comment: @BoltClock that would work also.  How would I do that?

Comment: just a side note: if you do this through javascript, there will most likely be a flash of unstyled content. Note sure if that is something you wanted to avoid or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said in comment, PHP will be a better way.

You can simple doing it like this :

```
<?php

$header = file_get_content('header.html');

$page = 'about.php';

$header = str_replace('<li><a href="'.$page.'">', '<li id="active"><a href="#">', $header);
```

Comment: how would I load it as a string?

Comment: In your PHP, how do you retrieve your menu ?

Comment: require("modular/header.php");

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question and put the code of header.php into please ?

Comment: I have edited my response. Your header is not a PHP file, so rename it in header.html (even if it's not a proper HTML file, but it's an other problem : you should find a better way for your templates), then, just echo $header.

Comment: Consider using a complete and without content HTML file with pseudo variables inside you can replace with str_replace() after loading it with file_get_content()

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the ID (which should be a class, semantically speaking, IMHO) using PHP whilst generating the page. Using JS is not only troublesome (you have to go and check your location, probably match a regexp, etc), but also inelegant.

Comment: how would I do that using PHP.  For example, in my PHP page that contains my navbar, how would I know which page is calling it?

Comment: You use GET parameters, for instance. `http://your.domain/whatever?page=pagename`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that in common coding for javascript where you want a particular element to be 'active' or 'highlighted' or 'enabled', make use of the class attribute.  Your id attribute implies a static attribute of the data being used.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want.

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="home">
       <a href="#" id="current">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="about">
       <a href="about.php">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="news">
       <a href="news.php">News</a>
    </li>
    <li id="applying">
        <a href="applying.php">Applying</a>
    </li>
    <li id="currentResidents">
        <a href="current.php">Current Residents</a>
    </li>
    <li id="alumni">
        <a href="alumni.php">Alumni</a>
    </li>
    <li id="contact">
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pagePath = window.location.pathname;
var pageName = pagePath.substring(pagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var currentActive;

function setActivePage(page)
{
    if(currentActive)
        document.getElementById(currentActive).removeAttribute("class");
    document.getElementById(page).setAttribute("class", "active");
    currentActive = page;
}

if(pageName == "about.html")
    setActivePage("about");
else if(pageName == "otherpage.html")
    setActivePage("otherpage");
// Etc...
</script>
```

If you were using jQuery this may have been done in a better and lesscode way... but I assume you're not using it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You should use four spaces per line to indent your code. Not only does this display it in a neat code box, but it allows this site to syntax highlight it.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm in process of trying to learn how that's done :) Usually I posted such codes in forums and I used [code][/code] but here it's a bit different. I'll do some research on how things are being done here. :)

Answer (score 0):

While it *may* be possible (I haven't actually tried it), you would not typically change the id of an element in the page.  Instead, it would be a better approach to use `class="active"` instead of `id="active"`.

Also, you probably want to generate the appropriate html for it on the server-side, as you're building the rest of the page.  Something like this would work (though there are many different ways to build this code, depending on your server's implementation):

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='Home')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='About')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='News')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='Applying')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="applying.php">Applying</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='Residents')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="current.php">Current <br />Residents</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='Alumni')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="alumni.php">Alumni</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='Contact')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note:  I've also removed the `id="current"` attribute from the anchor (`<a ...>`), because I'm assuming that this would change depending on the current page as well, and it's unnecessary, because you can build CSS selectors to address the anchor, without giving it its own special id or class.

Here's what your CSS might look like:

```
#navlist li.active {
  /* css rules for the active LI */
}
#navlist li.active a {
  /* css rules for the active (a.k.a. "current") anchor inside the active LI */
}
```

hope this helps.

---

[edit]  As I said above, it all depends on the architecture of your php code.  But assuming that you have a bunch of php pages (eg: "Home.php", "About.php", "News.php", etc.); and each of those pages includes your nav code using something like: `require("nav.php");`.  Then you can just do the following in each of your main php files:

```
<?php
/* $currentPage, declared here, will be available to php code inside nav.php */
$currentPage = strtolower(basename(__FILE__));
require("nav.php");
?>
```

Just be sure that you set $currentPage, in each page's main script, somewhere prior to including your nav code (ie. before you call `require(...)`).  The nav code will then be able to "see" `$currentPage` and use it.

So, for example, if the above code is executed in a file called "About.php", then $currentPage will be set to "about.php" (filename gets converted to all lowercase by the call to `strtolower(...)`). Then, when "nav.php" gets included, it will be able to access `$currentPage` and "see" that we're on the 'about' page.

You can change my example above, as follows, to use values of $currentPage that were generated from the filename using the approach I've described here.

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='home.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='about.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='news.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='applying.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="applying.php">Applying</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='residents.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="current.php">Current <br />Residents</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='alumni.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="alumni.php">Alumni</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (($currentPage=='contact.php')?'active':''); ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is $currentPage and how to you get the value of it?

Comment: @zPesk - I just edited my answer to include the details you requested.  please see above.